# Is this a good idea: Class that sums pointers from a vector, such that equal comparison is fast

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, comparison

I've the case, where I've a collection of several `vector`s, containing pointers. The pointers are in no particular order. I like to come up with a way to check if a vector might contain the same pointers.

I come up with the idea to interpret the pointers as an integer and sum them. If the sum is the same for two vectors, the contained pointers must be the same as well. It works good and I have not seen any problem. However, there are cases where this idea will collide and return a false positive (report equal vectors when they are in fact different).

My question is, if there is a way go get around this collision?

Note: Sorting the vectors is not an option.

---

EDIT:
In my Application I've can have many such pointer-vectors. And now and then one is joining the collection (could be 1000 vectors). When this happen, I must be able to check if some other vectors already covers the same elements. If so, the newcomer is discarded. For keeping track of which pointers-vectors are already in the collection, I use now a `std::set` (my actual `PtrHasher` supports more operators than shown here). The operations needed to check uniqueness is therefore 1) linearly sum up all pointers, 2) check the set within constant time.

As written in my comment, my application can handle "some" false positive (discard a vector even if it's not already covered). Summation therefore works for me. The reason why I ask this question is really if there is some other way (or a better operation) that would minimise false positives further but give same performance.

An earlier implementation also used `std::set` for "coverage-checking" and the performance was by far worse.

---

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdint.h> // std::uintptr_t

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class PtrHasher
{
public:
    PtrHasher(vector<T> v) : hash(0) { 
        for(const auto i : v)
            add(i);
    }
    void add(T pointer) {
        hash += reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(pointer);
    }
    bool operator ==(const PtrHasher<T>& other) const {
        return hash == other.hash;
    }
private:
    uintptr_t hash;
};


int main() {

    vector<int> values{0,1,2,3,4};
    vector<int*> ptr1{ &values.at(0), &values.at(2), &values.at(4) }; // points to 0,2,4
    vector<int*> ptr2{ &values.at(4), &values.at(0), &values.at(2) }; // points to 4,0,2 i.e. same positions
    vector<int*> ptr3{ &values.at(4), &values.at(3), &values.at(2) }; // points to 4,3,2 i.e. not quite the same position

    PtrHasher<int*> hasher1(ptr1);
    PtrHasher<int*> hasher2(ptr2);
    PtrHasher<int*> hasher3(ptr3);

    cout<< (hasher1==hasher2) <<endl;
    cout<< (hasher1==hasher3) <<endl;
    cout<< (hasher2==hasher3) <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Summation is a poor choice for integrity checking or for checking duplicates.  You could have one pointer less than the average value and one higher and the answer would be the same as having two duplicate pointer values.

Comment: Do you need to stop searching when a duplicate is detected or can you wait to the end?  Using Boolean arithmetic may be more efficient than using an `if` statement at each slot.  Most comparisons involve a branch, which may disturb the processing efficiency.

Comment: I'm well aware of that - hence my question. In my application I can live with some false positives due to "averaging". But the less the better. I will update my question to comment on the intent, which I think has not been very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what I finally came up with. Instead of just adding pointers, I seed a random number engine with it and generate such a number. Since the seed is always reset to the value of the pointer, the same pointers generate the same random numbers but neighbour pointers with nearly the same address generate very different numbers.
Note, this is still not 100% save, but it's fine for my purpose.

```
/// Class for hashing ranges of pointers, such that they can be compared to a different hasher for containing (all) the same pointers, independent of their order.
template<typename T>
class PointerCollectionHash
{
public:
    /// Construct a hasher.
    PointerCollectionHash()
        : m_sum(0),
          m_generator(0)
    {
        assert( std::is_pointer<T>::value && "ERROR: must be pointer type.");
    }

    /// Hashes each element within a range and adds it. last is the past-the-end item.
    template<typename Iter>
    void add(Iter first, Iter last)
    {
        for(; first!=last; std::advance(first, 1))
            add(*first);
    }

    /// Hashes a pointer and adds it.
    void add(T pointer)
    {
      m_sum += hash(pointer);
    }

    /// Compares two hasher. Returns true if all their hashed pointers are equal, independent of order of hashing. 
    bool operator ==(const PointerCollectionHash<T>& other) const
    {
        return m_sum == other.m_sum;
    }

private:
    /// Hashes a pointer.
    std::uintptr_t hash(T pointer)
    {
      m_generator.seed( reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(pointer) );
      return m_generator();
    }

    /// Keeps the sum of the added pointers.
    std::uintptr_t m_sum;
    /// Use Mersenne Twister to obtain a "unique as possible"-hash for an given input. The Seed of the engine is set to the input and a number is generated.
    std::mt19937_64 m_generator;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The sum can be the same even the two vectors contains different pointers, for example, vector A contain {p1, p2}, vector B contains {p1+8, p2-8}. If there are no additional properties you can rely on, converting vector to map for comparison may be a solution.

```
bool compare(vector<int*> ptr1, vector<int*> ptr2)
{
    map <int*, bool> mapForPtr1;
    for each elememt in ptr1
    {
      mapForPtr1[element] = true;
    }

    for each element in ptr2
    {
        if (mapForPtr1[element] != true)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

the complexity goes slightly higher, from N to LogN. But it's slightly faster than sorting in general.

Comment: from N to log(N) would be great :)

Comment: Wouldn't a set be better? Then it would be the same as I was doing in the past. I however found that my posted solution works better.